# showing data in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

can anyone helping me about showing just value of property in angular,

code snippet in my html :

```
<p>{{ tag }}</p>
```

code snippet in my controller.js :

```
var resource = $resource('/about');
resource.query(function(result){
  $scope.tag = result;  
});
```

I'm using mongodb for database which contain data `{'name':'blablablablabla'}`,
when I run this code i get `[{'name':'blablablablabla'}]` in my browser, this is not what i want, i just want showing name value which is 'blablablabla' in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing the name property directly:

```
$scope.tag = result[0].name;
```

Answer (score 2):

[{'name':'blablablablabla'}] is an array containing 1 object inside. To access the name property of this object you can simply assign it as

```
$scope.tag = result[0].name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You get as result the entire JSON returned from your MongoDB.
What you want is to get just the name, so:

```
$scope.tag = result[0].name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a forEach on result, and $scope.tag will be:

$scope.tag = result[index].name;

Your array result must have only one element.